# Is there an argument for the width of the plotting area in forestplot()

Tags: r, r-forestplot

Is there an argument for adjusting the width to height ratio of the plotting area in forestplot()? I'd like to set the x-axis to be 2/3 of the height of the y-axis.

Thanks!

```
# Package
library(forestplot)

# Data 
test_data <- data.frame(coef=c(1.59, 1.24),
                        low=c(1.4, 0.78),
                        high=c(1.8, 1.55),
                        varname=c("aa","bb"),
                        varexplan=c("A very long description A very long description","A very long description A very long description"))

test_data$varexplan <- as.character(test_data$varexplan)
test_data$varname <- as.character(test_data$varname)

# Prepare text 
tabletext <- cbind(c(test_data$varname), 
                   c(test_data$explan))
# Plot
forestplot(tabletext,
           test_data$coef,
           test_data$low,
           test_data$high)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps somebody: package `forestplot` does provide an option to set the graph width, aptly named `graphwidth`, which requires an `unit` argument: for instance,

```
forestplot(tabletext,
       test_data$coef,
       test_data$low,
       test_data$high,
       graphwidth = unit(5, "cm"))
```

which is probably a slightly more elegant option if you want to make the plot area proportions independent of the exporting function.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the desired proportions when exporting the plot, e.g. with `png()`. The plot will be saved into your working directory.

```
h <- 1080

png(height = h, width=2/3*h, res=300)
forestplot(tabletext,
           test_data$coef,
           test_data$low,
           test_data$high)
dev.off()
```

***Yielding***

[image]